# how to multiply dictionary values which are multiples

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

How do I multiply the values of this dictionary by 2?

```
d = {'a': (1,2), 'y': (2,4), 'z': (10,3)}
```

I get this

```
for i in d:
    print(d[i]*2)

[1, 2, 1, 2]
[2, 4, 2, 4]
[10, 3, 10, 3]
```

but I want to achieve:

```
[2,4]
[4,8]
[20,6]
```

Comment: Do you mind telling us how you wish for the multiplying to occur? do you want to multiply the values of a : (b, c) with y : (d, e) in the form (bc, de) or (bd, ce)?

Comment: i would like to multiply every dictionary value by 2

Comment: You can try `[{k:(v1*2, v2*2)} for k,(v1,v2) in d.items()]`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attempting to multiply a tuple which is resulting in the duplication of the values in your tuple. Instead, to algebraically interact with your tuples, you must do so one value at a time.

```
for i in d:
    print(d[i][0]*2, d[i][1]*2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through dictionary values and multiply each element by 2, not tuples * 2:

```
d = {'a': (1,2), 'y': (2,4), 'z': (10,3)}

for x in d.values():
    print([y*2 for y in x])

# [2, 4]
# [4, 8]
# [20, 6]
```

What you are doing is:

```
>>> tupl = (1, 2)
>>> tupl * 2
(1, 2, 1, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to do list comprehension

```
d = {'a': (1,2), 'y': (2,4), 'z': (10,3)}
for k in d.keys():
    d[k] = [2*x for x in d[k]]

print(d)
{'a': [2, 4], 'y': [4, 8], 'z': [20, 6]}
```